# How to get GNU Make to tell me why it is rebuilding a target

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to tell `make` to show me a list of inputs to a target and which ones are triggering a rebuild because they have been modified?

Comment: I think `--debug` does something similar?

Comment: You can `@echo $?` to print those prerequisites which are younger than your target. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

Comment: @Vroomfondel: Ah that looks like what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the -d option in make to show detailed information about the dependencies and the commands being executed. For example, if you run make -d , make will show a list of the dependencies of the target, as well as the commands being executed and their output.

Additionally, you can use the -n option to show what make would do, without actually executing any commands. This is useful to see which targets would be rebuilt because their dependencies have been modified. For example, if you run make -n , make will show the dependencies of the target and the commands that would be executed, without actually executing them.

Comment: Right but will it tell me *which input caused it to execute a command*?

Comment: `-d` did tell me which inputs changed. It is very verbose but it works.

Comment: Newer versions of GNU make also support the `--trace` option which provides less verbose output with only information on which targets were created, and why.  You should be able to easily find these things in either the man page (run `man make`) or the online documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html  (note this describes the _current_ release of GNU make; if you have an older release your version might not support all options).